# How to find index of element in javascript if it present?

Tags: javascript, data-structures

Could you please tell me how to find the index. I have a problem

```
Given a sorted array and a target value, return the index if the target is found. If not, return the index where it would be if it were inserted in order.

You may assume no duplicates in the array.

Example 1:

Input: [1,3,5,6], 5
Output: 2
Example 2:

Input: [1,3,5,6], 2
Output: 1
Example 3:

Input: [1,3,5,6], 7
Output: 4
```

I tried like this

```
var searchInsert = function(nums, target) {
          if (target > nums[nums.length - 1]) return nums.length;
    if (target < nums[0]) return 0;
    let start = 0,
        end = nums.length - 1,
        mid = Math.floor((start + end) / 2);
    while (start < end) {
        if(nums[mid] == target) return  mid
        if(nums[mid] > target) end = mid -1;
        if(nums[mid] < target) start = mid +1;
        mid = Math.floor((start + end) / 2);
    }
    return nums.length %2 == 0 ? mid +1 : mid
};
```

my test case fails

```
Input
[1,3]
2
Output
2
Expected
1
```

my test case only fail when an element is not found I want to insert in perfect index

updated Answer

```
var searchInsert = function (nums, target) {
    if (target > nums[nums.length - 1]) return nums.length;
    if (target === nums[nums.length - 1]) return nums.length-1;
    if (target < nums[0]) return 0;

    if (target ===nums[0]) return 0;
    let start = 0,
        end = nums.length - 1,
        mid = Math.floor((start + end) / 2);
    while (start <= end) {
        if(nums[mid] == target) return  mid
        if(nums[mid] > target) end = mid -1;
        if(nums[mid] < target) start = mid +1;
        mid = Math.floor((start + end) / 2);
    }
    return  nums[mid] > target ? mid : mid + 1;
};
```

Thanks for the help this code works perfectly all test case

Comment: have you tried index of ?

Comment: It might be worth adding to your question that you're looking for a binary search algorithm. Otherwise the linear search answers will continue to pile up...

Comment: `return nums.length %2 == 0 ? mid +1 : mid` - i don't see, how the length of `num` has any effect here. Use `return nums[mid] > target ? mid : mid + 1;`

Comment: `see [1]
1
Output
undefined
Expected
0`

Comment: using this it break the solution

Comment: ah, true, you need another fix - the issue is, that in the given case, your `while` never executes even once, and the check, whether `nums[mid] === target` never runs. A simple check for this should suffice though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is with your last statement

```
return nums.length %2 == 0 ? mid +1 : mid
```

So in the last case your `mid = 1` as since the length of array is two you're adding `mid + 1`

One approach is to return the value from while itself in case your target isn't found in array, on condition when `start === end`

```js
const searchInsert = function(nums, target) {
  if (target > nums[nums.length - 1]) return nums.length;
  if (target <= nums[0] || nums.length === 0) return 0;
  let start = 0,
    end = nums.length - 1,
    mid = Math.floor((start + end) / 2);
  while (start < end) {
    if (nums[mid] == target) return mid
    if (nums[mid] > target) end = mid - 1;
    if (nums[mid] < target) start = mid + 1;
    if(start >= end){
      return nums[mid] > target ? mid  : mid + 1 
    }
    mid = Math.floor((start + end) / 2);
  }
};

console.log(searchInsert( [1,3,5,6], 5)) // 2
console.log(searchInsert([1,3,5,6], 2)) // 1
console.log(searchInsert([1,3,5,6], 7)) // 4
console.log(searchInsert([1,3], 2)) // 1
console.log(searchInsert([1,2,3,5], 4)) // 3
console.log(searchInsert([1,2,3,4,5,7,9,10,15], 8)) //6
console.log(searchInsert([0, 1, 3, 4], 2)) // 2
console.log(searchInsert([1],1)) // 0
console.log(searchInsert([0],1)) // 1
console.log(searchInsert([],1)) // 0
```

Comment: see failure case `[1]
1
Output
undefined
Expected
0`

Comment: Due to the `end = mid - 1` case, inversion can happen, `start > end`. An example for this is `searchInsert([0, 1, 3, 4], 2)`.

Comment: @ASDFGerte ahh that's a good case, was trying to see all the case but couldn't thought of this, see the update if that serves all the case, btw thanks for pointing out

Answer (score -3):

What you can try is using the `<Array>.indexOf(n)` and `<Array>.sort()` like so:

```
let arr = [1,3,5,6]
const needle = 0

function searchInsert (arr, needle) {
  let index = arr.indexOf(needle)

  if (index === -1) {
    arr.push(needle)
    arr = arr.sort((x, y) => x - y)
    index = arr.indexOf(needle)
  }

  return index
}
```

Comment: You are attempting an O(n) solution for a O(log(n)) problem. This itself wouldn't let me downvote, but OP already posted an almost functional binary search, which only has a very minor issue. The proposed code is therefore imho a downgrade.

Comment: Also, you gained the downvotes when the answer you posted did not answer the question at all. Your updated answer not only offers significantly worse performance than what OP already had, but ends up modifying the array as well.

Comment: I see. I'm very much willing to hear about the performance part as I am using this kind of code in most of my projects.

Comment: Linear search vs. binary search. O(n) vs O (log n).

Comment: Thank you @RobbyCornelissen!