# Look up what range a value is within, in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm building a ToC and am trying to figure out what chapter I'm currently scrolled to so that I can highlight it.

When the dom is loaded I build a kind of index for all headers:

```
let offset = [];
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    let headers = document.getElementById('content').querySelectorAll('h1, h2');
    let  = headers.forEach(h => {
        offset.push( {id: h.id, offset: h.offsetTop})
    })
})
```

And on scroll I check against the index to get the current ID:

```
getIds = () => {
    let id;
    offset.some(o => {
        id = o.id;
        return o.offset > window.scrollY -1;
    })
    console.log(id)
};
```

I'd like to build an index that I can use to just look up the index without looping through it all. Is this possible?

Comment: You mean building a binary tree?

Comment: Why `offset.some()`?

Comment: I think some looping will be necessary regardless. Given a sorted array and a number whose position you need to identify between a range in the array, you *will* have to iterate over the array.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Probably being used for the short-circuiting, `.find` would be a better choice

Comment: name should be `getId` instead of `getIds`

Comment: Your array of elements is sorted, so if you're worried about the performance of the iteration, you could implement an enhanced binary search. The enhanced part being that it should return the insertion point instead of -1 if an exact match is not found. [This implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60860336/3558960) showed up in a question last week.